# Parsley.js ignoring `trigger` value

Tags: javascript, validation, backbone.js, parsley.js

I'm using parsley to validate the forms in Backbone app and only want validation to run when I call `form.validate()`. This is because I'm dealing with a lot of the event logic in my views already and would just like to be able to validate on submit. According to [defaults.js](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/annotated-source/defaults.html) form input events should be disabled by default. However, this isn't happening for me and the parsley instance seems to be listening to change events after I call `$('#form').parsley(options).validate()` for the first time. The errors are displayed as expected but it will remove them from the DOM as soon as the incorrect values are fixed in the inputs. The desired behavior would be to not clear them until the next `.valdate()` call.

The code looks something like this:

```
// Backbone event handler for `onSubmit`
onFormSubmit: function(ev) {
  var form = $('#form').parsley({
    trigger: false,                 // <-- defined it explicitly for good measure
    errorClass: 'error',            // <-- Custom error class handlers
    successClass: 'success',
    errorsContainer: '#msg-box',
    classHandler: this.classHandler
  })
  if (!form.validate()) {return}

  // ...
  // do submit
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

The `trigger` option is in addition to the `change` that is binded after the first failure in `manageFailingFieldTrigger`.

Very hackish workaround for now, set trigger to an event that doesn't exist but contains the word 'change', like 'ignorechange'. I think that would work, but no promises for the future.

Best would be to propose a PR, maybe by treating `trigger=null` as a special value?